# Yii occational database access lost

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I have a website with 15 tables for a dance school all done in yii with admin to add different content. Development and deployment was more fun than pain, thanks to Yii, but now new issue has popped up. Occationally error says

```
 database table for active record 'somerecord' does not exist in database
```

this error just means table does not exist. But this only happens once in a while. Like once every half an hour or so or sometimes more frequently. Could this be a server issue? Even when this occurs, the site is quite fast, which makes me rule out high server load? Could this be specific to database server or something. Database is Mysql on localhost.

I am not using schema cache and no opcode cacher.

Yii version is 1.1.14

Comment: Yes, it could be. You should check server logs.

Comment: Are you sure your database configuration in config/main.php is correct? Is there a function with "tableName()" name in all of your models? Probably somethings is wrong with database connection and/or mysql server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's your DB server having problems, not Yii. I've worked with Yii for years and only see that error when the DB server is unresponsive.

Comment: the server administrator says there is nothing wrong....like the server load and database are ok....can you give me some tips on how to resolve this issue with server admin? Like tell him what to look for? This error comes and goes which is the major issue in resolving it Even sites which earlier worked ok now show this error in addition to this dance school site..   The admin asked us to fix permissions etc but they are already right

Comment: In our case we ended up tracking it down to DNS errors that happened intermittently. We were dealing with a remote database and one of our web instances would have DNS issues that caused this to come up.

Answer (score 0):

Adding schema cache seemed to reduce rate of this error. but now internal error pops up once in a while... It a server performance issue though..